# Hyphenation doesn't work with MS Edge mobile

Tags: windows-phone, microsoft-edge

CSS:

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-ms-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
```

Works fine in the desktop-version of Edge, but not on my Windows Phone 10. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

Go to http://mnater.github.io/Hyphenator/mergeAndPack.html and generate `Hyphenator.js` with your preferences, then use the class

```
.hyphenate {
    hyphens: auto;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
}
```

to set up the content.

For more info how to use #ttps://github.com/mnater/Hyphenator and a practical exemple it is posible use hyphens in Microsoft Edge Windows Phone 10 #ttps://www.scania.com/global/en/home.html use in headers .hyphenate

Sorry for my English, and only can put one link ( change # for h).

Att. Miguel N.

Para los hispano hablantes simplemente, generad el `Hyphenator.js` desde el enlace y luego usad la clase , lo sacareis .

Larga vida a Windows Phone!!!! o que dure un poco más.

Regards y Saludos

Comment: please avoid using other then english as all users cannot understand other languages

Comment: Hello, the first part is in English and the second is the same in Spanish, just to make life easier for some users.
The important thing I think is the answer and evidently that for my part all I wanted to say has been in English.

Greetings.

PS: Down with boredom.